# Pandas compute column value based on whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that contains **a list of dictionary on one column**, So now I need to update that list of dictionary value based on same data frame id, currently what I do is using the data frame as a lookup while calculating the value,

```
id          name                ancestors
55324862    CTICC       [{'id': '6197560', 'type': 'neighbor'}, {'id': '6155003', 'type': 'city'}]
6197560  Cape Town City [{'id': '910', 'type': 'city'}, {'id': '6046820', 'type': 'vicinity'},{'id': '55324862', 'type': 'continent'}]
6046820  Cape Town      [{'id': '165', 'type': 'country'}, {'id': '55324862', 'type': 'continent'}]
```

**What I do currently**

I made a loop up JSON file using the id and name column from the dataframe and iterate through each row of the dataframe and and use the lookup file to generate the ancestors name value.

**What I want to achieve**

```
id          name                ancestors
55324862    CTICC       [{'id': '6197560', 'type': 'neighbor','name':'Cape Town City'}]
6197560  Cape Town City [{'id': '6046820', 'type': 'vicinity', 'name':'Cape Town'},{'id': '55324862', 'type': 'continent','name':'CTICC'}]
6046820  Cape Town      [{'id': '165', 'type': 'country','name':'YXZ'}, {'id': '55324862', 'type': 'continent','name': 'XYZ'}]
```

**What I want to do:**

*I don't want to use a lookup file as I have around 700K records to lookup and set name, So is there any other way I can do this without using a lookup file?*

Comment: Why don't you store the dictionary keys as columns? That's more inline with expected pandas usage. Is it a fixed number of dicts per list?

Comment: If possible, I would use two different tables. One for the names, another one for the ancestors, so you can use pandas functions like `.map()` or `.assign()`

Comment: @forgetso No, number of dictionaries is not fixed inside the list, max 10

Comment: any way without using lookup, another table to achieve that on same dataframe?